# Jquery UI Autocomplete not working after dom manipluation

Tags: jquery-ui

I have been trying to implement the autocomplete and have come across a problem that has stumped me.  The first time I call .autocomplete it all works fine and I have no problems. If, however, I call it after I have removed some (unrelated) elements from the DOM and added a new section to the DOM then autocomplete does nothing and reports no errors.
Code:-

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'get',
    dataType : 'json',
    url : '/finance/occupations',
    cache:true,
    success:function(data){
        occupationList = data;
        $('.js-occupation').autocomplete({ 
            source: occupationList,
            messages: {
                noResults: '',
                results: function(){}
            },
            minLength : 2,
            select:function(event, ui){
                $('.js-occupationId').val(ui.item.id);
            }
        }); 
    }
});
```

The background to this page is that it contains multiple sections that are manipulated as the user moves through them.  Hide and show works fine and does not impact on the autocomplete.  However, if I do the following:-

```
          var section = $('.js-addressForm:last').clone();
          clearForm(section);
          $('div.addressDetails').append(section);
          $('.js-addressForm:first').remove();
```

Which gives the user the bility to add multiple addresses on the previous section then the autocomplete stops working.

Any suggestions or pointers on something obvious I am missing?

I have tried to put the initialisation of the autocomplete on an event when the element gets focus and it still does not work.

Comment: Is your autocomplete inside `.js-addressForm:first`..? Can we see the HTML or an online demo..?

Comment: Nope.. It is in a completely different section... Which is why it is a little strange.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in an online demo..?

Comment: Not without a lot of work.  The form is used for Finance applications and I would not want to put an online demo out there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the autocomplete after all other underlying objects.  If you F12, you will see that the list is "visible", however it is below and hidden by all instances created after it.

If you created a div with inputs (one input being the autocomplete), then you create the automplete then the dialog instances, the autocomplete will never show.  If you create the dialog then the autocomplete, no problem.  The problem is the z-order

Comment: The problems is not that they are not shown but that the autocomplete is doing nothing.  So the JS is not firing when I start to type after I have manipulated the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue. For now to fix this, i'm creating widget on the input once input is in focus. It will help you solve the issue.

You can look for the help on
[making sure some event bing only when needed](http://appendto.com/2010/07/configuring-ui-widgets-and-interactions-with-live/)

Sample code will look like this

```
$( "#target" ).focus(function() {
  //I don't care if you manipulated the DOM or not. I'll be cautious. ;)

   (function() {
  $( "#combobox" ).combobox();
    $( "#toggle" ).click(function() {
      $( "#combobox" ).toggle();
    });
   })();

  // use a flag variable if you want
});
```

This solved my problem. Hope its the solution you were looking f